# Where stringify Json which can use in IE7

Tags: jquery, json, stringify

`JSON.stringify` and `$.stringify()` doesn't work on **IE7**.

I want to know the source which can work on IE7.

I didn't find that code.

If you know, please tell me.

Comment: FYI, `$.stringify` does not work in *any* browser, because jQuery does not have such a method.

Comment: Thank you all!
I fix this problem using json2.js.